# Magento 2: Customer account create Date of Birth field seprate dropdown

Tags: magento2.4, date, drop-downs, create-account

I have to add Date of Birth as a seprate dorpdown DD MM YYYY formate in customer account create form and my account section.

I have implement `dob.phtml` and `dob-validation-dropdown.js` but not saving data, when submit create account form getting error.

**Error:**

> ValueError: bcsub(): Argument #1 ($num1) is not well-formed in
> /var/www/html/magento24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Math.php:259
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/magento24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Math.php(259):
> bcsub()
> #1 /var/www/html/magento24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php(385):
> Zend_Locale_Math::Sub()
> #2 /var/www/html/magento24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php(662):
> Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat dob in one field as **yyyy-mm-dd** in controller. and then magento will save dob automatically